# __reversed__ Magic method

Tags: python, magic-methods

I have class Count which takes 3 parameters including self, mystart and myend. It should count from mystart until myend (also reversed)  using magic methods `__iter__`, `__next__` and `__reversed__`.  I have implemented all three magic methods. But I am still not sure whether it is the right way to implemnet next and reversed methods. Is it possible that I can call built-in functions next and reversed inside my  `__next__` and `__reversed__` methods or is there any pythonic way?

```
class Count:

    def __init__(self,mystart,myend):
        self.mystart=mystart
        self.myend=myend
        self.current=mystart
        self.reverse=[]


    def __iter__(self):
        "Returns itself as an Iterator Object"
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.current > self.myend:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            self.current+=1
            return self.current-1

    def __reversed__(self):
        for i in range(self.myend,self.mystart,-1):
            self.reverse.append(i)
        return self.reverse


obj1=Count(0,10)
print("FOR LOOP")
for i in obj1:
    print (i,end=",")

print ("\nNEXT")
obj2=Count(1,4)
print(next(obj2))
print(next(obj2))

print ("Reversed")
print(reversed(obj1))
```

Comment: In order for us to know what the "right" way is, what is the desired result. Your code doesn't look that bad

Comment: But I am creating a new list in my __reversed__ method which does not give me good feeling. :)

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to give an iterator a `__reversed__` method. That's for sequences and other multi-shot iterables with an ordering notion.

Comment: You're right in that it's probably not "the right way".  "The right way" would be to make `__reversed__` a generator of some sort.  Using `yield` would probably be the easiest approach.  (You'll have to compute the indices going backwards, but this doesn't seem too difficult given your example)

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up Iterators and Iterables:

Iterators:

1. Keep a state associated with their current iteration progress
2. Implement `__next__` to get the next state
3. Implement `__iter__` to return themselves.

Iterables:

1. Contain (or define with some rule) a collection of elements that can be traversed
2. Implement `__iter__` to return an iterator that can traverse the elements
3. can implement `__reversed__` to return an iterator that goes backwards.

[The `__reversed__` magic method is:](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__reversed__)

> Called (if present) by the reversed() built-in to implement reverse
>   iteration. It should return *a new iterator object* that iterates over
>   all the objects in the container in reverse order.

So you probably don't want to implement an iterator that can be `__reversed__` mid iteration, for example the implementation [in your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38750543/5827215) means that this code:

```
x = Count(1,10)
for i in x:
    for j in x:
        print(i,j)
```

Will cause an infinite loop, the output is just this pattern repeated:

```
1 4
1 3
1 2
1 1
```

the reason for this is because both `for` loops are changing `self.current` in opposite directions, the outer loop will increment it by 1 then the inner loop will set it to `self.myend` and lower it back to 0, then the process repeats.

The only way to properly implement all three magic methods is to use two classes, one for the iterator and one for the iterable:

```
class _Count_iter:
    def __init__(self, start, stop, step=1):
        self.current = start
        self.step = step
        self.myend = stop

    def __iter__(self):return self

    def __next__(self):
        #if current is one step over the end
        if self.current == self.myend+self.step: 
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            self.current+=self.step
            return self.current-self.step


class Count:

    def __init__(self, mystart,myend):
        self.mystart = mystart
        self.myend = myend

    def __iter__(self):
        return _Count_iter(self.mystart,self.myend,1)
    def __reversed__(self):
        return _Count_iter(self.myend, self.mystart, -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Now I have done it using yield statement. @jedwards thanks for your tipp.

```
class Count:

    def __init__(self, mystart,myend):
        self.mystart = mystart
        self.myend = myend
        self.current=None

    def __iter__(self):
        self.current = self.mystart
        while self.current < self.myend:
            yield self.current
            self.current += 1 

    def __next__(self):
        if self.current is None:
            self.current=self.mystart                
        if self.current > self.myend:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            self.current+=1
            return self.current-1

    def __reversed__(self):
        self.current = self.myend
        while self.current >= self.mystart:
            yield self.current
            self.current -= 1

obj1=Count(0,10)    
for i in obj1:
    print (i)

obj2=reversed(obj1)
for i in obj2:
    print (i)

obj3=Count(0,10)
print (next(obj3))
print (next(obj3))
print (next(obj3))
```

Comment: Note: your `__next__` method is useless, because when iterating python will call `__next__` of *the generator* returned by `__iter__` (add a `print` and check that it is never called). this said `current` is now only a *local variable* for `__iter__` and `__reversed__` so you should really just use `current` in place of `self.current` and remove `self.current = None` from `__init__`.